# Download build artifacts from file share does not show drop folder content

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

At the end of the build, I publish artifacts to a file share drive.

But in the release pipeline, if I select the Agent job, I don't see the content of the drop folder, as shown below. Do I have to use a Download Build Artifacts task to go around this ? Or can I still use this option of the Agent job somehow ?

[image]

The artifacts were correctly published to the file share. However I also noticed that I cannot open the artifacts folder from the build log. I only see the path. How come  ?

[image: artifacts published]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Download build artifacts from file share does not show drop folder content

This is an expected behavior. When we choose publish artifacts to a file share drive instead of Azure pipeline, the share drive can be our local path or a network shared folder.

So this share drive is **more controlled by us than azure devops**. In this case, Azure devops cannot provide a direct download link, only the path where we store the file.

> Do I have to use a Download Build Artifacts task to go around this ?
>   Or can I still use this option of the Agent job somehow ?

It depends on **whether your agent running your release pipeline can access your share drive**.

If yes, just like Shayki Abramczyk said, the agent will download the artifacts from the file share at the beginning of release.

Note: You need set the build pipeline as artifact source:

[image]

The output:

[image]

If the agent could not access that share drive, we need use the task like Download artifacts from file share to download the artifact.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior of publishing to a file share, you can't "explore" the files inside Azure DevOps if it stored on a file share.

You don't need to use the Download Build Artifacts task because the agent will download the artifacts from the file share at the beginning of his run.