# Azure Devops - Release pipeline. How do I share the fileshare to on prem VM

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm just trying to get my fist Release pipeline underway.

Our current infastrucure setup is that we have a number of On Prem VM's which I have deployed the Azure Agents as per the deployment group setup.

The issue I have at the moment is that the deployment first tries to download the artifact from our build server using a file share.

[image]

However, currently the deployment machine cant see the file share.  I gather I am supposed to be able to see the file share.  I'm not entirely sure how to share this folder on the build machine?

Am I supposed to just create a share for everyone to see?  Or is there a particluar user/role that I am having to share it for?

Comment: Update your build process to not publish to file shares. Azure DevOps can natively store build outputs without using file shares, then download them to the appropriate agent machines during deployment. For more specifics, you'll need to share more details about your pipeline, such as providing the YAML.

Answer (score 0):

> Our current infastrucure setup is that we have a number of On Prem VM's which I have deployed the Azure Agents as per the deployment group setup.

You need to check which user is used to run the tasks on the agent. You can add a powershell task with inline script: `whoami`.

[image]

You need to make sure the account have access to the file share.
[image]

In addition, when you publish artifact, you can select file share to store the artifact and then you can consume the artifact in the release pipeline. Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62186567/14996050) for the details.

My "Download artifacts from file share" in release pipeline screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Although not technically correct - I did learn a couple of things here.

1. After logging onto the VM.  I can right click the Azure Agent service and use credentials to use
2. As you pointed out I could change the fileshare location

Neither of these proved fruitless as it turns out.  It is on our newtwork but not on our domain.  I have resorted to using hosted pipelines instead.